# Mysterious height issue cross browser

Tags: html, css

I have two children of the body element. Both the HTML and BODY elements are styled to height:100%. As for the children, the first has a fixed height of 100px and the other is set to height:100%.

HOWEVER, doing this displaces the second child element visually, pushing it down the page and creating a side scroll bar. Effectively, this child IS 100% the height of the body and html tags, but because it comes after the first child of 100px, the entire section is displaced down the page 100px and creates a side scroll bar.

I could use overflow: hidden on the one of the parent elements to clip this excess off, or use a negative margin on the second child to draw it back, but I'd prefer not to.

Ideally, the second element will come directly after the first child, and stretch to the bottom of the window and no more. I want the section#content to respond to viewports, so I don't want to set a explicit height for it either.

I've tried various positioning techniques on the parents and children, but still not what I'm after.

For example, setting the parent element to position absolute and pinning in to all four corners of the screen has no effect on the child elements height. It still maintains the proper height but still is effected by that 100px offset.

Here is some simple HTML:

```
<body>
   <section id="header"></section>
   <section id="content"></section>
</body>
```

I've set the html and body height to 100%, and given #header a height of 100px.

section #content I've given a height of 100%, but the problem is this section expands PAST the window height.

Here is my simple CSS:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
section{
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
#header{
    height:100px;
}
#content{
    background:white;
    height:100%;
}
```

Any idea what's going on here? And more importantly, how to fix it??

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've added a negative `margin-top` of `-100px` to `#content` (headers height) + added `position: relative;` to `#header`. Is that what you're looking for?

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/breadadams/1zptzjwr/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you said it yourself what is going on... You are placing a full height element after a `100px` height one. So, your document has a height of `100% + 100px`. Nothing mysterious so far.

There are many approaches to create this kind of layout. My favorite involves using a `display: table` layout, that will auto size itself.

But a simple fix would be to use `calc()` on the second height (if you are not concerned about old IE versions...)

```
#content{
    background:white;
    height: calc((100%) - 100px);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Viewport-Percentage (or Viewport-Relative) Lengths:
These units are vh (viewport height), vw (viewport width), vmin (viewport minimum length) and vmax (viewport maximum length).

Try This.[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/0ec8b322/)

**Html:**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <section id="header"></section>
        <section id="content"></section>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Css:**

```
      body{
    height:100vh;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
section{
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
#header{
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}
#content{
    background:red;
    height: calc((100%) - 100px);
}
```

Comment: please add comment for negative .